# How to order by a field in an another model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two tables here, one is called `SystemPushLog` and another called `UserPermission`, they are both have a `user_id` field with `IntegerField`.Th `User` class would be populated when retrieving user info from rpc calls.

```
class User:
    is_authenticated = True

    class Meta:
        pass

    def __init__(self, info: dict = None):
        info.pop('user', None)
        for k, v in info.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
        self.id = info.get('id')
        self.avatar = dict(meta={}, url=info.get('avatar'))
        self.username = info.get('username')
        self.email = info.get('email')
        self.pk = self.id
        self.SNO = self.id
        self.phone_num = info.get('phone_num')

class SystemPushLog(models.Model):
    ...
    user_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class UserPermission(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    expire_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)  # 会员过期时间
    ...
```

The reason why they are chosen `IntegerField` rather than an `Foreignkey` is bacause the `User` model is in another system. And we have to retrieve user info by `gRPC` remote function calls. So, we just save the `user_id` as an `IntegerField`.

Now, I am stucking in how to order by `expire_datetime` field on another model `UserPermission` in queryset of `SystemPushLog`. The two table does not have relations except sharing the same `user_id` field.

I have tried to implement using raw SQL like this:

```
        qualified_ids = [item.id for item in queryset]
        queryset = SystemPushLog.objects.raw("""RAW SQL IGNORED""")
        ordered_log_ids = [item.id for item in queryset]

        clauses = ' '.join(['WHEN id=%s THEN %s' % (pk, i) for i, pk in enumerate(ordered_log_ids)])
        ordering = 'CASE %s END' % clauses

        queryset = SystemPushLog.objects.filter(id__in=ordered_log_ids).extra(
            select={'ordering': ordering}, order_by=('ordering',)
        )  # Now the queryset is ordered...
```

But, it runs really slowly. Maybe it is because of `clauses = ' '.join(['WHEN id=%s THEN %s' % (pk, i) for i, pk in enumerate(ordered_log_ids)]) ordering = 'CASE %s END' % clauses` If u know how to order the `expire_datetime` in a faster way, pls tell me.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `User model is in another system`?

If it's in another database or some other external source, then I would create a model "User" in your django project, which would model the User object in this another system - there in the User model, you can use the IntegerField as pk, and in the UserPermission and SystemPushLog you can have foreign keys to that user model.

So in UserPermission instead of `user_id` you would have something like:
`user = ForeignKey(model=User, related_name="permission")`

and in SystemPushLog:
`user = ForeignKey(model=User, related_name="system_push_log")`

This way you will have a relation between UserPermission and SystemPushLog through the User. Then to sort by expire_datetime you can do something like:
SystemPushLog.objects.all().select_related("user__permission").order_by("user__permission__expire_date").

However I guess you will have multiple logs and multiple permission per user - in this case it will be more complicated, because you will have many different user permissions per a single SystemPushLog, so you would have to choose the one you want to sort by (for example the newest one).

Either way, I would start with creating a User model, this will create the necessary relation between SystemPushLog and UserPermission.

Edit: added this after your comment:
What I mean is create a separate class representing the User in your database. For example:

```py
class UserModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primaty_key=True)
    # If you need any more data about the user in your database, add it here as proper fields.
```

In the User class, you can update your init class to also create a model instance, so that the data in your database is consistent with what you have in the User model.

Another way, if that works for you, is to change the existing User class to be a model:

```py
class User(models.model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    avatar = models.JSONField (using json field to store dict in the model)
    username = models.CharField()
    ...
```

Comment: I have edited the post and added the `User`. It is just a  normal class, and I do not know how to implement a virtual model that other models can use ```user = ForeignKey(model=User, related_name="permission")```. This is what we want to achieve all the time, and could u give me some guide.

Comment: But, there is a question. If I continue to use the `User` class and add a new model `UserModel`. It may hard for me to keep the insistence between `User` and `UserModel`.How do I know its time to update the updated userinfo into `UserModel` or just update everytime when initializing a User class if its already exists in `UserModel`?

Comment: With the simplified model (only id) you would have to only worry about initializing and deleting the User, because id will not change. From the database point of view you would just have a separate table with IDs, which will be used to link SystemPushLog and UserPermission. The rest of the User data would still be stored in your User class.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. I'll have a try. Thx a lot.